# API images not displaying as they should

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have the following JavaScript file which is calling to an API and displaying a carousel based on the images received:

```
let area = document.getElementById("area");
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url = "https://s.yimg.com/cv/apiv2/default/20200528/test.json";
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        let array = data.data;
        let imageArr = [];
        array.map(each => {
          imageArr.push(each.image)
        });
        imageArr.map(each => {
          let slide = document.createElement('div');
          slide.setAttribute('class','slides', 'fade');
          area.appendChild(slide);
  
          let image = document.createElement('img');
          image.src = each;
          slide.appendChild(image);
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Fail");
    }
}  

/* PREV */
let prev = document.createElement('a');
prev.innerHTML = "PREV";
prev.setAttribute('class', 'prev');
prev.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target){
    showSlides(slideIndex += -1);
  }
});
area.appendChild(prev);

/* NEXT */
let next = document.createElement('a');
next.innerHTML = "NEXT";
next.setAttribute('class', 'next');
next.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target){
    showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
  }
});
area.appendChild(next);


var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}  // goes back to the first one  
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length} // goes to the last one
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

The HTML is a simple div:
`<div id = "area"> </div>`

When receiving the images, they are all displayed and the function showSlides only works once I click the prev or next buttons.

Does anyone know why this is?

It should only show one image at a time.

Comment: Probably because you are calling the function for the first time, before any images actually exist. Your AJAX request is asynchronous

Comment: As @CBroe sain if `slides` be emtpy `showSlides` function has error for first execution.

Comment: This is the only way I've learned to communicate with an API. Could you please advise what to change with the code to make it only call when there are slides?

Comment: Actually I found a great article explaining my issue. Thanks guys!